# (C++) Не получается передать переменную string ( в MainFomr.h) в функцию которая находится в классе (Module.cpp/Module.h)

Tags: c++, c++-cli

При запуске программы пишет

> *E0415    не существует подходящего конструктора для преобразования из "*System::String ^" в "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator>"  Your Hotel*".

Я пытаюсь создать переменную string и дать ей данные из textbox и потом поставить в функцию, но выдает ошибку.

Вот сам код:

*MyForm.cpp*

```
//...
string NamePerStr = System::Convert::ToString(NamePer->Text);
SaveToFile(vipboxCheck, NamePerStr);
//...
```

*Module.cpp*

```
int SaveToFile(bool vip, string NamePerStr)
{
  //...
  ofstream fout;
  fout.open("../Data.txt", ofstream::app);

  if (!fout.is_open())
  {
    // error
  }
  else
  {
    fout << "==============================";

    switch (vip)
    {
    case 1:
      fout << "| VIP |==============================" << endl;
      break;

    case 0:
      fout << "=====================================" << endl;
      break;

    default:
      break;
    }

    cout << NamePerStr << endl;
    //...
    fout.close();

  return 0;
}
```

*Module.h*

```
int SaveToFile(bool vip, string NamePerStr);
```

Я пытался делать так

```
String^ NamePerStr = System::Convert::ToString(NamePer->Text);
```

Тоже не получается - дает ту же ошибку, пробовал через вектор из стрингов сделать - тоже не получается (мне лучше всего из вектора заполнить так как много данных)

Comment: System::String ^ нельзя так просто приравнять к std::string

Answer (score 0):

Спустя пару ночей пыток с  и разными способами я разобрался.

Нужно подключить `using namespace System::IO;` в пространство имен в файле MyForm.h.
Потом подключить библиотеку  в класс или туда же в MyForm.
И в функции где вы хотите записать данные в файл нужно написать

```
StreamWriter^ file = gcnew StreamWriter(path, ofstream::app);
```

где path это путь к файлу где он будет создан напр. "../../Skin.ini".
а ofstream::app это класс от fstream который позволяет дописывать значение не стирая все (это можно убрать уставив только путь).

Дальше просто прописывать имя файла и WriteLine где писать текст или переменные.
А потом его надо закрыть.

```
file->WriteLine("Text" + "," + smth);
file->Close();
```